# Keepalived split brain issue

Tags: linux, ip, virtual, firewalld, keepalived

I have issue with keepalived on Oracle Linux 8. The VIP is assigned to both nodes and both nodes are in MASTER mode.

**My keepalived configuration is:
**
Node 1
cat /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

```
global_defs {
  vrrp_priority -20
  checker_priority -19
  script_user root
}

vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
  script "/usr/bin/killall -0 haproxy" # check the haproxy process
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
  timeout 3
  fall 3
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  interface ens192 # interface to monitor
  state BACKUP # MASTER on haproxy1, BACKUP on haproxy2
  nopreempt
  virtual_router_id 52
  priority 101 # 101 on haproxy1, 100 on haproxy2
  virtual_ipaddress {
   VIP_adcat /vardress  # virtual ip address
  }
  track_script {
    chk_haproxy
  }
}
```

Node 2
cat /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

```
global_defs {
  vrrp_priority -20
  checker_priority -19
  script_user root
}

vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
  script "/usr/bin/killall -0 haproxy" # check the haproxy process
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
  timeout 3
  fall 3
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  interface ens192 # interface to monitor
  state BACKUP # MASTER on haproxy1, BACKUP on haproxy2
  nopreempt
  virtual_router_id 52
  priority 100 # 101 on haproxy1, 100 on haproxy2
  virtual_ipaddress {
   VIP_adress  # virtual ip address
  }
  track_script {
    chk_haproxy
  }
}
```

**I have added rules to firewall:**

firewall-cmd --list-all

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: here are ip addreses of both nodes
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 3306/tcp 3305/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
   rule family="ipv4" destination address="224.1.0.0/16" accept
   rule family="ipv4" destination address="224.0.0.18" protocol value="ip" accept
   rule protocol value="vrrp" accept
```

When I disable firewalld everything is ok and working, but with started firewalld I get both nodes with VIP.

In the logs I can find log: Keepalived_vrrp[1077307]: (VI_1) Receive advertisement timeout

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any health check in your config - maybe there's a default, since your firewall changes behavior.  You need to figure out which port your health check uses and open it to other keepalived nodes.

Comment: Health check does not use classic port, it is vrrp protocol and it is added to fw.